# Python 3 with Requests trying to use Tumblr API, I get error 401?

Tags: python, oauth, tumblr

I have Python 3 and I am trying to post to Tumblr via API [link to API documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2). I keep getting an error 401 despite feeling like I am doing everything correctly. There is an official API client in Python 2 but that feels a bit hard to follow and all other mentions of it seem to be in PHP or Java. I also am not sure of the format to post in after the 401 error because the documentation doesn't give any explicit examples other than /post. My code:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
#variables for later
client_key=""
client_secret=""
oauth_token=""
oauth_token_secret=""

#gets the values for the variables
with open("API.txt", 'r') as readAPI:
    readAPI.readline()
    client_key=readAPI.readline()[23:]
    client_secret=readAPI.readline()[23:]
    oauth_token=readAPI.readline()[23:]
    oauth_token_secret=readAPI.readline()[23:]
readAPI.close()

#prints them to double check they are being read correctly
print(client_key)
print(client_secret)
print(oauth_token)
print(oauth_token_secret)

#sets oauth for the connection
oauth = OAuth1(client_key,
               client_secret,
               oauth_token,
               oauth_token_secret)

#check post that should return various blog stats
r = requests.get("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info" ,auth=oauth)

print(r)
```

I am 100% sure I am getting the client key, the client secret, oauth token and oauth token secret correct. I have double checked, the oauth tokens are both put in the file that is being read manually and they are printed before the connection attempt. I am 100% sure it is correct. I'm wondering if Tumblr's API is broken?

Edit: This is with print(repr())

```
'client_key'
'client_secret'
'oauth_token'
'oauth_token_secret'
{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

This is what happens after trying a new code and with Steven's method with JSON.

```
b'{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
print(client_key)
```

What is the output of this?

```
print(repr(client_key))
```

You're using `readline`, which includes a newline character at the end of each line:

```
$ cat foo.txt
key
secret
blabla

$ python3.4
>>> f = open("foo.txt")
>>> print(repr(f.readline()))
'key\n'
>>> print(repr(f.readline()))
'secret\n'
>>> print(repr(f.readline()))
'blabla\n'
```

Have you tried stripping the newline character off of each line?

---

**Edit**: Updating my post based on @user2853325's comments. Your code works for me under Python 3.4, requests==2.5.2, and requests-oauthlib==0.4.2.

API.json (redacted the keys/secrets):

```
{
    "client_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXdG7zXIMcDidwQ5pMHuQTbxyhNINrCE",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX72A5HQO1axydP5nlOWCTQx4ECfXfyX",
    "oauth_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8WAnqMBWaAdnGhnc4gWhJ4j6cufK1W",
    "oauth_token_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8Kf82k65JzIcMU7QUp54ssPEzJd7my"
}
```

tumblr.py:

```
import json

import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

#gets the values for the variables
with open("API.json") as f:
    credentials = json.load(f)

#prints them to double check they are being read correctly
print(credentials)

#sets oauth for the connection
oauth = OAuth1(
    credentials['client_key'],
    credentials['client_secret'],
    credentials['oauth_token'],
    credentials['oauth_token_secret']
)

#check post that should return various blog stats
r = requests.get("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info", auth=oauth)
print(r)
print(r.content)
```

Output (redacted the oauth stuff):

```
$ bin/python tumblr.py
{'oauth_token_secret': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8Kf82k65JzIcMU7QUp54ssPEzJd7my', 'client_secret': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX72A5HQO1axydP5nlOWCTQx4ECfXfyX', 'client_key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXdG7zXIMcDidwQ5pMHuQTbxyhNINrCE', 'oauth_token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8WAnqMBWaAdnGhnc4gWhJ4j6cufK1W'}
<Response [200]>
b'{"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"},"response":{"user":{"name":"lost-theory","likes":0,"following":2,"default_post_format":"html","blogs":[{"title":"Untitled","name":"lost-theory","posts":0,"url":"http:\\/\\/lost-theory.tumblr.com\\/","updated":0,"description":"","is_nsfw":false,"ask":false,"ask_page_title":"Ask me anything","ask_anon":false,"followed":false,"can_send_fan_mail":true,"share_likes":true,"likes":0,"twitter_enabled":false,"twitter_send":false,"facebook_opengraph_enabled":"N","tweet":"N","facebook":"N","followers":0,"primary":true,"admin":true,"messages":0,"queue":0,"drafts":0,"type":"public"}]}}}'
```

So now that I've tested your code out for myself:

- How did you get the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`? I got mine by clicking "Explore API" on the [Applications developer page](https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps).
- You don't need to call `readAPI.close()`, as the `with` block automatically closes the file for you (see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)).
- I used JSON for storing and reading the credentials, that way I'm 100% sure that I'm getting the correct strings. The code is cleaner too. I'm still suspicious about the way you're reading lines from the file and slicing them.
- Try printing `r.content` in your code the same way I am. Does it give you a more descriptive error message than "401 Unauthorized"?

Comment: I added .replace('\n','') to each of the values and updated the question with what it shows. Basically repr has just added '' around my values.

Comment: I see you were right about the \n though as I just tried it without. Good call on that! It still says 401 for some reason though. :(

Comment: Tough for me to say without registering for the API and trying it myself. Instead of using requests, could you try using the official API client in python2? Or in another language? Or with curl (if possible)? If that works, then it must be something in your code. I wouldn't count on their API being broken, most likely you are missing a step in authenticating. OAuth can be a little tricky.

Comment: Also, this might not be your problem, but slicing this way: `readAPI.readline()[23:]` can be a little error-prone. When you're slicing that way it's very easy to make an off-by-one error (i.e. why is it 23? should it be 22 or 24 instead?). Maybe try to put the credentials directly into the python code just as a test, to make sure you're passing in the correct stuff. It would be a little cleaner to store the credentials in JSON or configparser format.

Comment: It is 23 because that's the amount of characters I have before the code. I print the code before trying to make sure it is being read right and it is, although I hadn't thought about the \n. I can't try with curl and I am not comfortable with downloading python2 just for this as I've read it has given some people installation errors.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works for me. Take a look at the update to my post.

Comment: I am copying your JSON format and using that instead. It still doesn't work for me for some reason. I also re-requested the tokens and it still doesn't work. I'll update with the exact message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71555/discussion-between-user2853325-and-steven-kryskalla).