# Requests library sending POST to get a value

Tags: python, http, oauth, python-requests

My question is: **How I can get the oauth_verifier value by sending requests with the mighty `requests` library in python ?**

I'm trying to avoid having to launch a browser to get the oauth_verifier value that's used to obtain the oauth_token and the oauth_secret.

Using a browser the process is quite simple. You pass the `oauth_token` and `oauth_callback` to the `oauth/auhorize` endpoint url

```
https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=bVnvTtjYPPndeuCiuHDJPOoTIkEaMD5WRBfRbkguZmf4l8x4Yz&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F
```

Then you can authorize it pressing the green button "Allow" ("Permitir" in Spanish).

**RIGHT CLICK > OPEN IMAGE IN NEW TAB to see FULL SIZE**

[image]

After this, the page is redirected with another `GET` param, the `oauth_verifier`, that is what I need to obtain the token and the token secret keys.

But I'm trying to avoid this by doing the login with python `Requests` library, and then submiting the form or sending POST/GET requests to allow it and get the `oauth_verifier` parameter without a browser.

Here are the **headers / cookies / params** generated when browsing the oauth/authorize?... url.

**RIGHT CLICK > OPEN IMAGE IN NEW TAB to see FULL SIZE**

[image]

Here the POST generated after clicking the "Allow" green button:

**RIGHT CLICK > OPEN IMAGE IN NEW TAB to see FULL SIZE**

[image]

It has a status code "**302 Moved Temporarily**" And then redirects to the url  that results in the other GET request, now with the **oauth_verifier** parameter that I needed.

[image]

Comment: How much of the OAuth process do you understand? Did you see [`requests-oauthlib`](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) yet?

Comment: There is also [`tumblpy`](https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-tumblpy) if you are specifically working with Tumblr.

Comment: See [Python 3 with Requests trying to use Tumblr API, I get error 401?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28685520) for someone getting `requests` and Tumblr OAuth to work with `requests-oauthlib`.

Comment: I'm using pytumblr to perform a Three Legged Oauth1.0a with the endpoints shown here. https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth

But, I wasn't able to get the token and token_secret without using a browser.  As they suggest here https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr there are two ways of getting the credentials... 1 by using the interactive console that requires prompt of the user, and 2 by using the browser and going here https://api.tumblr.com/console

Are you suggesting thats possible to avoid using the browser with these mentioned libraries ???

Comment: You need to request a API token and secret, then create new sessions each time with that. The initial setup you do with the API console.

Comment: But once you have those, you don't need to go to the console each time, no.

Comment: Also see the [`interactive_console.py` script](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/blob/master/interactive_console.py) which retrieves an OAuth token & secret given a consumer key & secret; that interaction you also can run with `requests-oauthlib`.

Comment: The use of the `interactive_console.py` script was my 1st option in the comment above. It needs the consumer_key and consumer_secret, but then you must input the `oauth_verifier` in the `raw_input()` part... In my tests I've found that script outdated. And I had to modify it to make it work. Also, I had to retrieve the `token` and `token_secret` key for every session that I wanted to create. Are you completely sure that I only need to retrieve the 4 keys once ??? Thank you !

Comment: The point of OAuth is that you are given temporary tokens each time, to access private information from 3rd parties on Tumblr. That's why there is a browser involved, the 3rd party needs to approve the access each time. You cannot work around that part, because that'd let you access any 3rd party content without their consent! Now, if you are accessing your *own* things, then you don't need to use the whole OAuth process, and your consumer key is your API key for that access.

Comment: So, yes, if you need access to any part of the API that requires full OAuth tokens, then you have to go through the hoops to have the 3rd party authorise you for that access.

Comment: I need posting, that requires oauth. But what stops us from using the requests library ? It can't replicate the same requests sent to authorize the app by the browser ?? It would be a security flaw and its prohibited ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76245/discussion-between-jesus-flores-and-martijn-pieters).